# Exclude Exempt Users from MFA using API

Tags: api, mfa

Following this article - [Exclude Exempt Users from MFA](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_mfa_exclude_exempt_users.htm&type=5)
I would like to get the `Waive Multi-Factor Authentication for Exempt Users` permission using API.
During the investigation I found `BypassMFAForUiLogins` but I don't find it in the API references.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Metadata API docs aren't always complete. It _sounds_ like this might be right permission. Have you tried applying it by deploying the metadata? You can post an answer to your own question with the results of your investigation, it would help the community.

Comment: Found the variable in Metadata API Developer Guide -> [Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm)

Using Workbench I could find: **PermissionsBypassMFAForUiLogins**.
Thanks.